Proxmox: error on backups: backup connect failed: command error: Invalid argument (os error 22)
I have a proxmox instance and I added a proxmox backup server as datastorage, everything seems to be fine but when I try to generate a backup I've got this error:
INFO: starting new backup job: vzdump 100 --mode snapshot --node pve --remove 0 --notes-template '{{guestname}}' --storage pbsexternal
INFO: Starting Backup of VM 100 (qemu)
INFO: Backup started at 2024-07-23 09:33:04
INFO: status = running
INFO: VM Name: figserver02
INFO: include disk 'scsi0' 'disk2:vm-100-disk-0' 32G
INFO: backup mode: snapshot
INFO: ionice priority: 7
INFO: creating Proxmox Backup Server archive 'vm/100/2024-07-23T14:33:04Z'
INFO: issuing guest-agent 'fs-freeze' command
INFO: issuing guest-agent 'fs-thaw' command
ERROR: VM 100 qmp command 'backup' failed - backup connect failed: command error: Invalid argument (os error 22)
INFO: aborting backup job
INFO: resuming VM again
ERROR: Backup of VM 100 failed - VM 100 qmp command 'backup' failed - backup connect failed: command error: Invalid argument (os error 22)
INFO: Failed at 2024-07-23 09:33:06
INFO: Backup job finished with errors
TASK ERROR: job errors

I have no clue what is wrong, can you please help me?

Do you have the qemu guest agent installed? Which version? Is it logging anything on the VM?

The proxmox version is 7 and the qemu-guest-agent is installed on every virtual machine.

proxmox 7 is a dead end, update first and retry

Which version of AGENT?

it turns out that the filename contain colon characters and the destination partition (extfat) does not support them, any idea how to change the name of vzdump files
